# Redirect php form on successful submit

Tags: php, redirect

At the moment after a form is submitted, the following code is used:

```
<?php
if(isset($error))
    {echo "<span id='Warning'>Please enter all areas marked with *</span>";}
else if (isset($sent))
    {echo "<span id='Normal'>Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you shortly</span>";}
?>
```

How can I redirect to a THANK YOU page upon submit (if there are no errors of course)?

The form action is currently:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['../PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="enquiryform">
```

I've tried the following after my sql query execution. I would like to redirect this page to a thank you page only on successful form submission (without any errors)

```
header('Location: THANK YOU PAGE');
```

I'm sure it's something fairly obvious, but I've searched everywhere and tried lots of different things to no avail!

Full code (obviously removing server info, email addresses and form content as it's fairly long etc):

```
<?php

/* Accessing SQL-Server and querying table */
MYSQL_CONNECT($server, $user, $password) or die ("Server unreachable");
MYSQL_SELECT_DB($database) or die ("Database non existent");

if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST))
{
$adate = $_POST['adate'];
$guests = $_POST['guests'];
if($guests=="Please Select")
{
$error['guests'] = 'Flagged';
}
$title = $_POST['title'];
if($title=="Please Select")
{
$error['title'] = 'Flagged';
}
$name = trim($_POST['fullname']);
if(empty($name))
{
$error['name'] = 'Flagged';
}
$telephone = trim($_POST['telnumber']);
if(empty($telephone))
{
$error['telephone'] = 'Flagged';
}
$accomm = trim($_POST['accommodation']);
if($accomm=="Default")
{
$error['accommodation'] = 'Flagged';
}   
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pattern = '/^[^@]+@[^\s\r\n\'";,@%]+$/';
if (!preg_match($pattern, trim($email)))
{
$error['email'] = 'Flagged';
}
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

//initialize variables
$to = 'EMAIL@EMAILADDRESS.COM';
$subject = "Enquiry";

 //build the message
$email_message .= 'Arrival Date: '.$adate.' Guests: '.$guests.' Accom: '.$accomm."\n\n";
$email_message .= 'Name: '.$title.' '.$name."\n\n";
$email_message .= 'Telephone: '.$telephone."\n\n";
$email_message .= 'Email: '.$email."\n\n";
$email_message .= 'Message: '.$message;

$additionalHeaders = "From: XXXXXXXXXXXX<".$email.">";
//print_r($error);
//send the email

if (!isset($error))
{
     mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $additionalHeaders);

MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT into Enquiry VALUES('".date('d/m/y')."','".$_POST['hSpa']."','".$_POST['hPackage']."','".$adate."','".$guests."','".$accomm."','".$title."','".$name."','".$telephone."','".$email."','".$message."')");
}
}
?>
</head>

<body id="body">

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['../PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"    id="enquiryform">

            <p>Areas marked with * must be completed</p>

                <label class="enquiryform" id="message" for="message">Message</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="9" cols="55" tabindex="9" onclick="removeDefaultText(this)"><?php if(isset($error)) {echo $message;} else {echo "Please use this area for any other information about your enquiry";}?></textarea>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send enquiry" tabindex="10" />

</form>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($error)) {
echo "<span id='Warning'>Please enter all areas marked with *</span>";
}
else if (isset($sent)) {
header("Location: THANK YOU PAGE.HTML");
exit();
}
?>  
</div>
```

Comment: correct, what's wrong with this?

Comment: the correct use would be: `"../".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: thanks @Lucius - it works as it is, so maybe I don't need to change it?! Thanks for your comment though

Comment: what's the output in the 'action' attribute of the form? if it's empty (like I suspect), the form automatically sends its data to its own page..

Comment: also, please note that the header function will work **only if no other output is sent before its call**, otherwise it will throw a fatal error, that's the reason why I set that function in my answer, muting `header` and falling back to a javascript redirect (you may use a meta refresh as well) in case it fails..

Comment: so, please move your `if .. elseif` code to the top of the page, so that the call to header comes before any other output, otherwise it will NEVER work.. or else, use the function I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

you could set a function like this:

```
function pageRedirect ($page) {
    if (!@header("Location: ".$page))
       echo "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.replace('$page');</script>\n";
    exit;
}
```

then use it in your code like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($error))
    echo "<span id='Warning'>Please enter all areas marked with *</span>";
else 
    pageRedirect ($thankyoupage);
?>
```

You can then put all the thankyous ant the blahblah in the thankyou page

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
exit();
```

after the header call.

```
<?php
if(isset($error)) {
    echo "<span id='Warning'>Please enter all areas marked with *</span>";
}
else {
    header("Location : thank you page");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: have you put the header directive inside your elseif (isset($sent)) {} statement ?

Comment: @Motley9735 the header call and exit should be in your else if code

Comment: No Ben - the php error/thank you directive is separate to the header directive. Should the two be together and how would this look?

Comment: Emaillenin - thanks again. How would this look?

    
    <?php
 if(isset($error))
  {echo "<span id='Warning'>Please enter all areas marked with *</span>";}
 else if (isset($sent))
  header('Location: THANK YOU PAGE');
 exit();
 ?>


Thanks so much guys - as I'm sure you can tell, I'm new to all of this and learning my way, slowly!

Comment: @emaillenin - I would if this worked, but it never. If there are errors it still displays the error message, however upon submitting with no errors, it doesn't redirect you to the THANK YOU PAGE.

Any ideas?

Comment: Error is if they haven't completed all of the required fields and $sent is where the data is added to the database, where they should then be redirected to the THANK YOU html page

Comment: I am having a problem understanding the flow of your code. It will be helpful if you post the complete source code.

Comment: where are you assigning the $sent variable?

Comment: @Motley: can you debug whether the code run through else clause?

Comment: add echo "Checking if else loop is working.."; exit(); before the header call and check if you are able to print these after filling the form correctly..